# I'm trying to redefine the product definition in haskell. I get an error saying "Non-exhaustive patterns in function"

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching

```
product' :: [Integer] -> Integer
product' (x:xs)
  | (x:xs) == []   = 1
  | otherwise = x * (product' (xs))
```

The first one doesn't work and gives the errror. The one below is using the pattern matching technique and works fine.

```
productP :: [Integer] -> Integer
productP [] = 1
productP (x:xs) = x * (productP (xs))
```

Comment: `(x:xs) == []` is non-sensical, since this can *never* happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `(x:xs) == []` part is non-sensical: with `(x:xs)` you *construct* a list with at least one element: `x` as first element, and `xs` as a (possibly empty) list of remaining elements. This will therefore *always* result in `False`.

The point of a `(x:xs)` pattern is that it matches *non-empty* lists. A list is defined as:

```
data [a] = [] | (a:[a])  -- pseudo-code
```

A list thus has two data constructors:

1. the empty list `[]`; and
2. the "cons" `(x:xs)` which has a head `x`, and a tail `xs`. `x` is an element of the list, and `xs` is a list of remaining elements.

You could check if `xs`, the entire list, is equal to the empty list, and then use `head` and `tail`:

```
product' :: [Integer] -> Integer
product' xs
  | xs == []  = 1
  | otherwise = head x * product' (tail xs)
```

But the above is *not* very elegant, since `head` and `tail` are non-total functions (well they error for empty lists), it is thus "harder" to determine that this function will always produce an answer.